# Derive union type from tuple/array values

Tags: typescript

Say I have an array:

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Is it possible to derive from this value union type that is `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`?

I want this because I want to define type which allows only values from static array, and also need to enumerate these values at runtime, so I use array.

Example how it can be implemented with an indexed object:

```
const indexed = {a: null, b: null, c: null}
const list = Object.keys(index)
type NeededUnionType = keyof typeof indexed
```

Is it possible to do it without using an indexed map?

Comment: So essentially, you'd like to generate types on the fly?

Comment: The types only exist when compiling, so you can't create them dynamically at runtime.

Comment: This is an interesting question. What is your use case?

Answer (score 492, accepted):

### CURRENT ANSWER

In TypeScript 3.4 and above, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to retain the specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of any [literal values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#literals) in an expression.

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; // const assertion
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c';
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gcgIaYDQyYBG+hwmAujNhDKJFANwwD0LMAKgMoDMAdABYYEAJ5go2AB4AoKCIAOAUxgA5RYoAmmgKpgE4DguVo5SkADN4SKOjABXALZFFAJwrM2hXAB9imX+SMQA)

### UPDATE Feb 2019

In [TypeScript 3.4, which should be released in March 2019](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#34-march-2019) it will be possible to tell the compiler to infer the type of a tuple of literals *as a tuple of literals*, instead of as, say, `string[]`, by using the [`as const` syntax](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510).  This type of assertion causes the compiler to infer the narrowest type possible for a value, including making everything `readonly`. It should look like this:

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; // TS3.4 syntax
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c';
```

This will obviate the need for a helper function of any kind.  Good luck again to all!

---

### UPDATE July 2018

It looks like, starting with TypeScript 3.0, it will be possible for TypeScript to [automatically infer tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).   Once is released, the `tuple()` function you need can be succinctly written as:

```
export type Lit = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
export const tuple = <T extends Lit[]>(...args: T) => args;
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
const list = tuple('a','b','c');  // type is ['a','b','c']
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c'
```

Hope that works for people!

---

### UPDATE December 2017

Since I posted this answer, I found a way to infer tuple types if you're willing to add a function to your library.  Check out the function `tuple()` in [tuple.ts](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/381562d282ebaa9b41217d1b31e2c211).  Using it, you are able to write the following and not repeat yourself:

```
const list = tuple('a','b','c');  // type is ['a','b','c']
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c'
```

Good luck!

---

### ORIGINAL July 2017

One problem is the literal `['a','b','c']` will be inferred as type `string[]`, so the type system will forget about the specific values.  You can force the type system to remember each value as a literal string:

```
const list = ['a' as 'a','b' as 'b','c' as 'c']; // infers as ('a'|'b'|'c')[]
```

Or, maybe better, interpret the list as a tuple type:

```
const list: ['a','b','c'] = ['a','b','c']; // tuple
```

This is annoying repetition, but at least it doesn't introduce an extraneous object at runtime.

Now you can get your union like this:

```
type NeededUnionType = typeof list[number];  // 'a'|'b'|'c'.
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution for a problem I run into quite often, when I need runtime checks (using the tuple) and compile time checks using a type union.  Anyone knows if there are efforts to add support for implicit tuple typing to the language?

Comment: Tried your solution but it does NOT work with `cont xs = ['a','b','c']; const list = tuple(...xs);`

Comment: It's not supposed to work with that, since by the time you do `const xs = ['a','b','c']` the compiler has already widened `xs` to `string[]` and completely forgotten about the specific values.  I can't help that behavior at least as of TS3.2 (there might be a future `as const` notation that works though).  Anyway I think the answer as stands is still as correct as I can make it (I mention in there that `['a','b','c']` is inferred as `string[]`) so I'm not sure what more you need.

Comment: can someone explain what  `[number]` does in `list[number]` ?

Comment: It's parsed as `(typeof list)[number]`... not `typeof (list[number])`. The type `T[K]` is a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) which gets the type of the property of `T` whose key is `K`. In `(typeof list)[number]`, you're getting the types of the properties of `(typeof list)` whose keys are `number`. Arrays like `typeof list` have [numeric index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), so their `number` key yields the union of all numerically-indexed properties.

Comment: Just a follow up question: 
Would this solution be correct if the array was dynamically built?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c'] as const` gives the type `readonly ["a", "b", "c"]` which might not be what we want.
`['a' as const, 'b' as const, 'c' as const]` gives type `("a" | "b" | "c")[]` which is probably what we want.

Comment: Can someone update for 2022?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing to update (except possibly for changing future tense to present or past tense); `const` assertions are still the way to do this.

Comment: Can this be done from a generic?
`function getValue<T extends string[]>(values: T, predicate: any): QUESTION`

What should be in QUESTION to ensure the call to `getValue(['a', 'b'])` limits the return value to `'a' | 'b'`?

Comment: I found a way: `type GetValueFn = <T extends readonly string[]>(values: T ) => T[number];`

Answer (score 30):

### Update for TypeScript 3.4:

A new syntax called **"const contexts"** that will arrive in TypeScript 3.4 will allow for an even simpler solution that doesn't require a function call as demonstrated. This feature is currently in review [as seen in this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510).

In short, this syntax allows for the creation of immutable arrays that have a narrow type (i.e. the type `['a', 'b', 'c']` instead of `('a' | 'b' | 'c')[]` or `string[]`). This way, we can create union types from literals as easy as shown below:

```
const MY_VALUES = <const> ['a', 'b', 'c']
type MyType = typeof MY_VALUES[number]
```

In alternative syntax:

```
const MY_VALUES = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
type MyType = typeof MY_VALUES[number]
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are living on TypeScript after March 2019 now. (It's November 2021)

I'm just extending [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257357) with an exportable utility function:

```js
// Your handmade utils' library file
export type UnionOfArrayElements<ARR_T extends Readonly<unknown[]>> = ARR_T[number];
```

```js
// Usage
const a = ["hi", "bye", 3, false] as const;
type ta = UnionOfArrayElements<typeof a>; // false | "hi" | "bye" | 3

const b = [4, 5, 6];
type tb = UnionOfArrayElements<typeof b>; // number
```

Comment: this works great when you have some third-party types of the form `("foo"|"bar")[]` and you want to extract the string-literal union type of possible values.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do this with Array.

The reason is, even if you declare the variable as const, the content of an array can still change, thus @jonrsharpe mention this is runtime.

Given what you want, it may be better to use `interface` with `keyof`:

```
interface X {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

type Y = keyof X  // Y: 'a' | 'b'
```

Or `enum`:

```
enum X { a, b, c }
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain fields? For instance, if I want only the `a` field..

Comment: You can use `Pick<T, U>` for that.

Answer (score 0):

If using a an object for storing "constants", this is a way to implement the same idea:

*(Note the 'as const' to change the type of keyOne and keyTwo from string to literal.)*

```
const configObj = {
  keyOne: 'literalTypeValueOne' as const,
  keyTwo: 'literalTypeValueTwo' as const,
};

const typeValues = [configObj.keyOne, configObj.keyTwo] as const;
type MyType = typeof typeValues[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's just a wrapper for `X[number]`, the [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) project offers [TupleToUnion](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/tuple-to-union.d.ts) which lets you do the same thing but perhaps more readably:

```js
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const

type NeededUnionTypeStandard  = typeof list[number]

type NeededUnionTypeAlternate = UnionToTuple<typeof list>
```

Note that the `as const` and the `typeof` are necessary.