# How to check if a given value is in a union type array

Tags: typescript

I have an array of given union type, then wants to check if a string from a superset of the union type is contained in the array (runtime check):

```js
const validOptions: ("foo" | "bar")[] = ["foo", "bar"]
type IArrType = typeof validOptions[number]
const key: IArrType | "alien" = "alien" // Rather: some random function
const isKeyInArr = validOptions.indexOf(key) > -1 // Error: "alien" is not assignable to "foo" | "bar"

// Fix 1:
const isKeyValidCast = validOptions.indexOf(<IArrType>key) > -1 
// Fix 2:
const isKeyValidExplicit = 
      key === "alien" ? false : validOptions.indexOf(key) > -1 // OK: type guard magic
```

Fix 1 is OK but not very elegant. Fix 2 fools the compiler but is misleading and inefficient runtime. In my case the "alien" string type is just a placeholder for any string not in the union type.

Is there any ways this can be compiled without casting or explicit tests?  Can the expression be negated so that we get this "type guard" to work?

BTW: This very cool answer show how to construct a typed tuple from a list of values: [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: Probably `(arr as string[]).indexOf(key)` is your best bet.

Comment: @jcalz - Yes, I agree that casting the arrary is better than casting the argument.   It's more clear to the intention of the code.  Ended up using a custom guard function and `find()`, however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The biggest problem is how to handle all possible values that are not `ConfigurationKeys` without explicitly checking each one. I named them *Configuration* as it's very common scenario.

You can hide logic behind your own guard function that tells compiler: *I can handle type checks, trust me*. It's recognized by `value is ConfigurationKeys` return type.

**Code example** *([live](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ConfigurationKeys%20%3D%20%22foo%22%20%7C%20%22bar%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isConfiguration(value%3A%20ConfigurationKeys%20%7C%20string)%3A%20value%20is%20ConfigurationKeys%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20allowedKeys%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20allowedKeys.indexOf(value)%20!%3D%3D%20-1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20key%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22alien%22%20%2F%2F%20Rather%3A%20some%20random%20function%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(isConfiguration(key))%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20key%20%3D%3E%20ConfigurationKeys%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20key%20%3D%3E%20string%0D%0A%7D))*:

```
type ConfigurationKeys = "foo" | "bar";

function isConfiguration(value: string): value is ConfigurationKeys {
    const allowedKeys: string[] = ["foo", "bar"];
    
    return allowedKeys.indexOf(value) !== -1;
}

const key: string = "alien" // Rather: some random function

if (isConfiguration(key)) { 
    // key => ConfigurationKeys
} else { 
    // key => string
}
```

I found writing own guard functions as very clean solution to work with Union types. Sometimes type casting is still needed, but here you hide casting and logic within single piece of code.

Reference:

- [User defined Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards)
- TypeScript doc: [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

Comment: I added a custom guard function and it does improve the code quality a little.  However I still need the cast, as my version of the `allowedKeys` structure is a tuple of typed strings.  Hence the `indexOf` expression will not compile without it.

Comment: It's fine to do type casting *within* guard function. That's the place where you check things possible in runtime but unforeseen in compile-time. Even in official doc their do so (see reference).

Comment: You could also use `find` which has different type definition that allows values different from base type. See: `allowedKeys.find(el => el === value) !== undefined`

Comment: Using `find` together with a custom guard gets me close enough.  The construct is easy to reason about, without any casts.  Thank you!

Comment: type ConfigurationKeys | string is collapsed to string by compiler, so you can simplify isConfiguration(value: ConfigurationKeys | string) to isConfiguration(value: string)

Comment: Type guards are great, but this is a dangerous pattern as currently written. If `ConfigurationKeys` ever changes and you forget to update `allowedKeys` to match, then you will have a type guard that is incorrectly validating strings at compile time *and* runtime. It's an easy change to type check `allowedKeys` against `ConfigurationKeys`.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer uses type assertions/casting but from the comments it appears the OP went with a solution using `find` that works differently. I prefer that solution also, so here's how that can work:

```js
const configKeys = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type ConfigKey = typeof configKeys[number]; // "foo" | "bar"

// Return a typed ConfigKey from a string read at runtime (or throw if invalid).
function getTypedConfigKey(maybeConfigKey: string): ConfigKey {
    const configKey = configKeys.find((validKey) => validKey === maybeConfigKey);
    if (configKey) {
        return configKey;
    }
    throw new Error(`String "${maybeConfigKey}" is not a valid config key.`);
}
```

Note that this can guarantee that a string is a valid `ConfigKey` both at runtime *and* compile time.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution combines elements of the answers from [Piotr Lewandowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085718/5799673) & [tschoonhoven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61131590/5799673).

It has the benefit of declaring the list of valid keys once (no need to update the array and the union type separately) and using a type guard function.

```
const configKeys = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
type ConfigKeys = typeof configKeys[number]; // "foo" | "bar"

function isConfigurationKey(value: string): value is ConfigKeys {
    return configKeys.indexOf(value as ConfigKeys) !== -1;
}
```