# Matching against possible type literals in Typescript

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching

Take the following minimal example:

```
type BinaryOp = 'MOV'
type UnaryOp = 'ADD' | 'SUB' | 'JRO'
const BinaryOps: BinaryOp[] = ['MOV']
const UnaryOps: UnaryOp[] = ['ADD', 'SUB', 'JRO']

type Line =
    { op: BinaryOp, a: number, b: number }
  | { op: UnaryOp, a: number }
```

And the following "pattern match":

```
switch (line.op) {
    case 'ADD':
    case 'SUB':
    case 'JRO':
        return `${line.op} ${line.a}`
    case 'MOV':
        return `${line.op} ${line.a}, ${line.b}`
}
```

I don't particularly like that, in order for the case to understand the op is a `UnaryOp` or a `BinaryOp`, I have to enumerate all the possibilities. Is there a compact(er) way to achieve this?

**NOTE.** Take into consideration that this is a simplified example, and there might be other kind of `Op`'s.

Comment: This is a minimal example; `default` would work in this particular case, but it's not semantically equivalent.

Comment: Abandoning the `switch` statement in favour of `if` and `else if` statements that call [user-defined type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) would be one way of solving the problem.

Comment: @cartant indeed, I just solved it that way, thanks :) Wanna answer the question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any TypeScript trickiness that can be used to avoid having to enumerate all of the `case` labels, as the labels are required to be values - not types.

However, you could use `if` statements instead of the `switch` and you could use [user-defined type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) within the `if` expressions.

A user-defined type guard is a function that has a return type that is a type predicate. For example, a user-defined type guard for a `UnaryOp` might look like this:

```
function isUnaryOp(op: string): op is UnaryOp {
  return op && UnaryOps.includes(op as any);
}
```

When used in `if` statements, user-defined type guards will narrow the type:

```
if (isUnaryOp(line.op)) {
  const op = line.op; // Inferred to be UnaryOp
} else if (isBinaryOp(line.op)) {
  const op = line.op; // Inferred to be BinaryOp
} else {
  const op = line.op; // Inferred to be never
}
```

Comment: Indeed, one could generalize the `isSomething` helper to `export function is<U, T extends U>(op: U, collection: Array<T>): op is T {
    return collection.includes(op as T)
}`

Comment: @HugoSerenoFerreira might I also suggest a method of ensuring the union and the array stay in sync https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771535/typescript-how-to-write-a-type-guard-to-tell-if-a-value-is-a-member-of-a-union/50771933#50771933