# How do I create a type from a string array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

What is the best way of making a TypeScript type based on an array of strings? I am on version 2.6.2. The array is long and I do not want to repeat myself by duplicating the string values in an Enum declaration.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
export type Color = convertStringArrayToType(colors);
```

The following solution [(source)](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html) works fine, but feels hacky:

```
/** Utility function to create a K:V from a list of strings */
function strEnum<T extends string>(o: Array<T>): {[K in T]: K} {
  return o.reduce((res, key) => {
    res[key] = key;
    return res;
  }, Object.create(null));
}

/**
  * Sample create a string enum
  */

/** Create a K:V */
const Direction = strEnum([
  'North',
  'South',
  'East',
  'West'
])
/** Create a Type */
type Direction = keyof typeof Direction;
```

Comment: What's hacky about it ? Hard to understand maybe, but it uses standard advanced types  in Typescript, I wouldn't change a thing

Comment: Note typescript also has string enums in recent versions `enum Direction {
        North = 'North',
        South = 'South',
        East = 'East',
        West = 'West'
    }` but it depends what you are trying to do

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, but I don't want to repeat the text unnecessarily, as I mentioned

Comment: Then it looks fine, what don't you like about the solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The custom function to convert it into something usable for creating the type

Answer (score 105):

Since Typescript 3.4, you could use `as const` and generate a union type from an array as follows

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'] as const;
export type Color = typeof colors[number]; // 'red'|'orange'|'yellow'|'green'|'blue'|'indigo'|'violet'
```

Comment: What is the magic `number` thing which converts it to `'something' | .. ` from `['something']` ?

Comment: Thats a good question. Basically you are creating a type `Color` which has the type of the array `colors` accessed at any index. Since `number` can take any numeric value, the type created is a union type of all the possible accessed entries of the array (`'red'|'orange'|'yellow'|'green'|'blue'|'indigo'|'violet'`)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @guido-dizioli's answer, you can create a reusable function to create a type dynamically and still benefit from IntelliSense:

[image]
One catch is that the caller needs to define the array with `as const`:

```
const properties = [
    "prepare", 
    "loadSession", 
    "proceedBasedOnSession", 
    "fetchConnection"
] as const;

function createObject<T extends readonly string[]>(steps: T): Record<T[number], object> {
    const typed = {} as Record<string, string>;
    steps.forEach(step => typed[step] = step);
    return typed as unknown as Record<T[number], object>;
}
```