# Is it possible to create a typescript type from an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I often use code such as

```
export type Stuff = 'something' | 'else'
export const AVAILABLE_STUFF: Stuff[] = ['something', 'else']
```

This way I can both use the type `Stuff`, and iterate over all the available stuffs if need be.

This works, but it feels like repeating twice the information. And you have to be careful because an update of either `Stuff` or `AVAILABLE_STUFF` also requires an update of its counterpart.

Is there a better way to define the type from the Array, or even to somewhat use the array to type some data ?

Comment: Do you want to fill the array with the types or what exactly is the use case to use the array like that?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz kind of. I would like to be able to profit from the benefits of both `const x: Stuff` and `AVAILABLE_STUFF.forEach(stuff => ...)` with only one declaration. I don't care if I have to declare an array, a type, or whatever else that I yet don't know about :)

Comment: Have you considered using a string [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)? That looks like it should do what you want. It is a type, and you can iterate the values.

Comment: Closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521808/how-do-i-create-a-type-from-a-string-array-in-typescript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One built-in option would be to use an enum instead of the type and array approach.

```
export enum Stuff {
    something = 'something',
    else = 'else',
}

export const AVAILABLE_STUFF: Stuff[] = Object.values(Stuff);
```

Another option is to extract the type from the type of `AVAILABLE_STUFF`. To do this we must force the compiler to infer a tuple of string literals for `AVAILABLE_STUFF`. This can be done in `3.4` with `as const` or before `3.4` using an extra function. After `AVAILABLE_STUFF` is a tuple type we can just use a type query to get the type of the elements:

```
export const AVAILABLE_STUFF = (<T extends string[]>(...o: T)=> o)('something', 'else'); // typed as ["something", "else"]
// export const AVAILABLE_STUFF = ['something', 'else'] as const; // typed as ["something", "else"]  in 3.4
export type Stuff = typeof AVAILABLE_STUFF[number] //"something" | "else"
```

A few explanations of the above code. `typeof AVAILABLE_STUFF` gives us the type of the constant (`["something", "else"]`) to get the `[number]` is called a [type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) and will give us the type of an item in the tuple.

The `(<T extends string[]>(...o: T)=> o)` is just an IIFE we use to force the compiler to infer a string literal tuple type. It has to be generic as the compiler will only infer literal types and tuples in certain cases (a type parameter with a constraint of `string` being one of them). The `as const` version is what I would recommend using when it becomes available as it is more readable.

Comment: In the second solution, I see that the type `Stuff` is correctly inferred but I don't understand the syntax. What is the role of `[number]` in `typeof AVAILABLE_STUFF[number]`?

Comment: @Paleo added some explanations let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: Second option works for me, but I'm still puzzled about `enum`. when I try `const x: Stuff = 'something'`  I get an error `Type '"something"' is not assignable to type 'Stuff'. ` Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @aherve it is not a perfect replacement. you will need to use `let a: Stuff = Stuff.something` in TS code. At runtime the value of `a` will be `something`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the answer and the explanation. My question is how can I use that approach for a function signature with rest params? For example, `const {bar3} = foo('bar1', 'bar2')` will throw an error, but `const {bar1} = foo('bar1', 'bar2')` will work. (If it should be a different question, let me know and I'll create one) - [Playground](https://mnmlurl.ml/#tMDWm)

Comment: @MoshFeu This should work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=30&pln=5&pc=22#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygHgCqLoAeU6YAJgM6KVSYxgDmAfABQB0nAhpo5QFyI8AbQC6ASkEAldCkzl8AGhp0GLRAG8AUIl2JM6KCExIefdgfIgI6VqwAOB1MojGDYKOMQBeZpp16gY7oqMKumO5QiKI+iADkXGAAnlAAFmpxiFzUiUkA3AGBugZGJojBqAWBAL7KGtVZ1DJyCnjKtPRMzOIF1VpaKGC0WRGxwglxynEARnGiBVBJ9uiI5LGLy3DAI5jCYCAAttNY8-2DwxpZiA3eyGhYUKwTU7M9WkA

Answer (score 37):

With TypeScript v3.4 [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```js
export const AVAILABLE_STUFF = <const> ['something', 'else'];
export type Stuff = typeof AVAILABLE_STUFF[number];
```

Comment: Why does it have to be `AVAILABLE_STUFF[number]` and not just `AVAILABLE_STUFF[]` ?

Comment: Because the "keys" in arrays are number.

Comment: This nearly worked for me but I had to do `['something', 'else'] as const` (`as const` instead of `<const>`) and then `(typeof AVAILABLE_STUFF)[number]` (added brackets).

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to create an object and use `keyof`. I recommend that way only if you have anything useful to store as values (in replacement of `null` in the code below).

```
const stuffDict = {
  something: null,
  else: null,
}

type Stuff = keyof typeof stuffDict
const AVAILABLE_STUFF = Object.keys(stuffDict) as Stuff[]
```