# How to tell TS that a non-assignable type is expected?

Tags: typescript, types

This code:

```js
type A = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
let a: A 
const list = ['a', 'b'] as const 
list.includes(a)
```

returns an error on `a`:

```
Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'.
  Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'
```

If type `"c"` is not assignable to type `"a" | "b"`, then `list.includes(a)` will return false, not error. So this is expected. Is there a way to tell it to understand that without having to use `//@ts-ignore`?

Comment: So you basically want to avoid type checking? Get rid of the `const`-assertion.

Comment: hmm, I need the const assertion to [create a typescript type from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55020193/3416774)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but how about you just use `a as any`?

Comment: hmm, that's weird. Isn't that `any` is even broader than `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`? So why does `includes()` accept this one and not the other?

Comment: `any` can be assigned anything and is assignable to anything. Essentially type check are turned off completely. That's usually something to avoid but in your case it doesn't make much of a difference since you only depend on the `boolean` value returnd by `includes()`.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Wouldn't using `//@ts-ignore` be better than using `any` if you really want to turn off type check? And since `any` provides semantic on the type, I guess there are cases it's better to use it rather than `//@ts-ignore`. I know this one is one case, but are there other cases where it's better to use it rather than `//@ts-ignore`?

Comment: This is probably material for a separate question. In short: `@ts-ignore` ignores errors for the entire following line while `any` can *disable* typing for certain variables. See this example [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwApYBzARgC54BnDGLVUgGnjICZq6GmBKagG44swANwBYAFBSA9DPgABDDQC0WUqhxwpiQkQCsrAGy8J0ybuL62NNqgCex01KA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, so much so that there is even a library to fix exactly this use case (https://www.totaltypescript.com/ts-reset, search for "Make `.includes` on `as const` arrays less strict").

Personally, I would simply use `list.includes(a as typeof list[number])`.

*Edit:* fixed type assertion

Comment: it seems that once you run the lib once, it will config the project, so even if you remove the import line, the effect of it is still there? (I use Deno on VS Code)

Comment: Not sure, I haven't used that library. But it doesn't look like it does any configuration, removing the import line should remove the effects of it. But it could be that it got cached by VS Code somehow, or maybe that simply having the library installed automatically imports it.

Comment: It must be cached in order to use it right? You don't check type at runtime, but import only works on runtime, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, caching is typically an implementation detail that doesn't affect the behavior of a system, except for performance. Import is used both at runtime (to know which functions to call), and at compile time (to know which types to use).

Comment: I forgot that you also use import to check type. I guess the behavior is some kind of "cache" in VS Code, not the runtime environment like Node or Deno. Refreshing the IDE seems to work. I haven't checked twice