# Typescript: Check "typeof" against custom type

Tags: typescript, types

I have a custom type, let's say

```
export type Fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "grape";
```

I would like to determine if a string is part of the Fruit type. How can I accomplish this?

The following doesn't work.

```
let myfruit = "pear";
if (typeof myfruit === "Fruit") {
    console.log("My fruit is of type 'Fruit'");
}
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Short answer:

You can't use `typeof` at runtime to check for `interface` types, which only exist at compile time.  Instead you can write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check for such types:

```
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grape"] as const;
type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number];
const isFruit = (x: any): x is Fruit => fruit.includes(x);

let myfruit = "pear";
if (isFruit(myfruit)) {
  console.log("My fruit is of type 'Fruit'");
}
```

Long answer follows:

---

You might be confused about the difference between values and types in TypeScript, especially as it relates to the `typeof` operator.  As you may be aware, TypeScript adds a static type system to JavaScript, and [that type system gets erased when the code is transpiled](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure).  The syntax of TypeScript is such that some expressions and statements refer to *values* that exist at runtime, while other expressions and statements refer to *types* that exist only at design/compile time.  Values *have* types, but they are not types themselves.  Importantly, there are some places in the code where the compiler will expect a value and interpret the expression it finds as a value if possible, and other places where the compiler will expect a type and interpret the expression it finds as a type if possible.

The `typeof` operator leads a double life.  The expression `typeof x` always expects `x` to be a value, but `typeof x` itself could be a value or type depending on the context:

```
let bar = {a: 0};
let TypeofBar = typeof bar; // the value "object"
type TypeofBar = typeof bar; // the type {a: number}
```

The line `let TypeofBar = typeof bar;` will make it through to the JavaScript, and it will use the [JavaScript typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) at runtime and produce a string.  But `type TypeofBar = typeof bar`; is erased, and it is using the [TypeScript type query operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) to examine the static type that TypeScript has assigned to the value named `bar`.

In your code,

```
let myfruit = "pear";
if (typeof myfruit === "Fruit") { // "string" === "Fruit" ?!
    console.log("My fruit is of type 'Fruit'");
}
```

`typeof myfruit` is a value, not a type. So it's the JavaScript `typeof` operator, not the TypeScript type query operator.  It will always return the value `"string"`;  it will never be `Fruit` or `"Fruit"`.  You can't get the results of the TypeScript type query operator at runtime, because the type system is erased at runtime.  You need to give up on the `typeof` operator.

---

What you *can* do is check the value of `myfruit` against the three known `Fruit` string literals... like, for example, this:

```
let myfruit = "pear";
if (myfruit === "apple" || myfruit === "banana" || myfruit === "grape") {
  console.log("My fruit is of type 'Fruit'");
}
```

Perfect, right?  Okay, maybe that seems like a lot of redundant code.  Here's a less redundant way to do it.  First of all, define your `Fruit` type in terms of an existing array of literal values... TypeScript can infer types from values, but you can't generate values from types.

```
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grape"] as const;
export type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number];
```

You can verify that `Fruit` is the same type as you defined yourself manually.  Then, for the type test, you can use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) like this:

```
const isFruit = (x: any): x is Fruit => fruit.includes(x);
```

`isFruit()` is a function which checks if its argument is found in the `fruit` array, and if so, narrows the type of its argument to `Fruit`.  Let's see it work:

```
let myfruit = "pear";
if (isFruit(myfruit)) {
  console.log("My fruit is of type 'Fruit'");
}
```

That type guard also lets the compiler know that inside the "then" clause of the `if` statement, that `myfruit` is a `Fruit`.  Imagine if you had a function that only accepts `Fruit`, and a value that may or may not be a `Fruit`:

```
declare function acceptFruit(f: Fruit): void;
const myfruit = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "pear" : "banana";
```

You can't call the function directly:

```
acceptFruit(myfruit); // error, myfruit might be "pear"
```

But you *can* call it inside the "then" clause after checking it:

```
if (isFruit(myfruit)) {
  acceptFruit(myfruit); // okay, myfruit is known to be "banana"
}
```

Which is presumably why you want to check against your custom type in the first place.  So that lets you do it.

---

To recap: you can't use `typeof`.  You can compare against strings.  You can do some type inference and a type guard to eliminate duplicated code and get control flow type analysis from the compiler.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EtYF4YG0BEBDABwIBsBTHAGhhwCM8x69LqBzBQ8gXRjwhlEhQA3AFgAUFACeBUjABiyNDEwAKKTJBx4iqAEosYJAFsapBJ1FiB0GCggLUGGCoAeALh5hJujy9t8HJXQAPm1HADoUMGBiJAATUghXXUsyWCNJREdlahk8BBxLFC0VO0CoFQystF1dGABvcRh+cAgQMnDiEBYVHABZSTClOxhNGHVZAHJyyZwU8QBfcXEEmPzZOCRoqBRwHmBgUgIocpU4D3KfGAA3EBQ4yyqdHL68KAALcPYwOJAjFTqAB4YAAGcIAVhgAH5cqR8jgYB5aIwGIVxHgDkcTjpKpkdCkYAB6QkwMwIEAIKhPbJGFAsd6wUyw+HiYrOMo46k1OqNMTNDGHY6nLl6IREkkgADWeEkVLx2RGkrAIAA7mBxiAYEzkQxUYsgA)

Comment: Thanks for explanation about getting type from array! Was wondering if it's really possible, just checked myself - worked perfectly.

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer, thank you! The only thing I had to change was `const isFruit = (x: any): x is Fruit => fruit.includes(x);` - instead of `fruit.includes(x)`, I had to write `fruit.indexOf(x) !== -1`. Otherwise, I received the following error: `Property 'includes' does not exist on type ...`

Comment: Yeah, [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is an ES2016 feature and might not be present if you are transpiling down to ES5 or ES2015.

Comment: This has to be one of the most interesting and informative S/O answers I have ever read. Thanks!

Comment: It's indeed a great post. I however struggle to understand how this line
 type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number];
is working

Comment: `typeof fruit` is `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">`, so `Fruit` is equivalent to `(Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">)[number]`.  The syntax `T[K]` means: the type of the properties of `T` whose keys are of type `K`. So `(Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">)[number]` means "the types of the properties of `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">` whose keys are of type `number`", or: "the array elements of `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">`, or: `"apple" | "banana" | "grape"`.

Comment: amazing explanation.  is anything like this covered in the official docs?  I'm especially amazed at this line: ````export type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number]````.  How can someone come up with that???

Comment: [Link to other @jcalz comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values#comment99063812_45257357) explaining how does `(typeof fruit)[number]` work.

Comment: Indeed this is helping a lot of people, don't even joke about deleting it!! LOL Thank you so much!! Even knowing a bit about TS, these explanations are great to help us grasp the bits that are still foggy for some of us. :)

Comment: One quibble with this solution: `Fruit` will type check as a regular string variable, so you won't be able to take advantage of type hinting, i.e your IDE won't suggest "grape" as a possible value and it won't complain if you say `fruit = 'broccoli';`. I guess this is a case choosing whether the explicit check is more important.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm against typescript. Custom function to check a custom type? Why bother with TS?

Answer (score 9):

### `typeof` in TS:

The `typeof` operator in TS can be used in 2 different contexts:

1. In an expression/value context to return a string of its type. This is just the JavaScript `typeof` operator and will remain after a compile.
2. In a type context to make the type similar to an existing expression/value. This is a TS construct to help us express ourselves more easily with certain types. This will be compiled away and not be present in the compiled JavaScript

### Examples:

Expression/value context

```js
const hi = 'hi';
const one = 1;
const obj = {};

console.log(typeof hi, typeof 1, typeof obj);
// [LOG]: "string",  "number",  "object"
```

Type context:

```
const obj1 = {foo: 1, bar: true};
const obj2 = {foo: 1, bar: ''};

// test has the type according to the structure of obj1
const test: typeof obj1 = {foo: 1, bar: true};
// typeof obj1 is the same as:
type sameAsTypeofObj1 = {foo: number, bar: string}


// test2 has the type according to the structure of obj1
const test2: typeof obj2 = {foo: 1, bar: true};
// In test2 we get a compile error since bar is not correct
// Since the type of obj2 is {foo: number, bar: string} we get the error:
// Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

---

For your specific problem I think you should use user defined type guards. Here is an example:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "grape";

let myfruit = "apple";

// user defined type guard
function isFruit(fruit: string): fruit is Fruit {
  return ["apple", "banana", "grape"].indexOf(fruit) !== -1;
}

if (isFruit(myfruit)) {
    // if this condition passes 
    // then TS compiler knows that myfruit is of the Fruit type
    console.log(`${myfruit} is a Fruit.`}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a string array from the 'Fruit' type instead of hard-coding it?

Comment: @Alex.A, the other answer covers this.

Comment: I don't understand why we have to write a `isFruit` method, while it could be deduced from the type itself, with an operator like `is(Fruit)`. This is so verbose and not DRY!

Answer (score -3):

## Generic type checking

If anyone else is looking for a generic version of a `isFruit` function, I was able to come-up with a check.

```js
const isType = <Type>(thing: any): thing is Type => true;
```

This allows you to check different types without needing different type-checking functions.

```js
if (isType<Fruit>(food)) {
  food.eat();
} else if (isType<Vegitable>(food)) {
  food.roast();
}
```

Comment: This will fail in practice because there is no runtime check whatsoever happening here. If you strip away the TypeScript, it boils down to `if (true) food.eat()`, regardless of whether food is a vegetable or not.