# Checking if string variable belongs to union type definition

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I have a `type` definition, imported from a different npm package, that consists of over 100 strings in union, like this:

```
type SomeType = "a" | "b" | "c" \\ | ... and it goes and goes
```

I would like to check in my code if a string variable belongs to this `SomeType`. Is there a way to do that which **does not** require me writing helper functions listing all the possible values ([as described here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147575/check-if-variable-belongs-to-custom-type-in-typescript))?

In my case, listing all the values might not be the best, as the type values from that npm package may change in the future and because there is a load of them. I'm looking for some smarter way, if it exists.

Comment: Typescript types/interfaces are not transpiled into code, which means, the checkup you want to do is impossible. A better approach would be to define that type as an enum, then check your value against that enum

Comment: @MorShemesh: The OP writes that the type is from a third-party package not under their control. They *cannot* change it to an enum.

Comment: Missed that - you're right

Comment: Do you want to **typecheck** if a string is one of the described values or check during **runtime** with e.g. an if statement?

Comment: @zzrv I need to do it in the runtime. Sorry, for being imprecise

Answer (score 0):

One of [typescript goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) is to performs a fully type erasure on javascript ouput.

Actually (typescript v3.8) the union of literal types like:

```
type SomeType = "a" | "b" | "c";
```

are not converted into runtime values of some sort.

If implemented the [proposal of spread operator on Union types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17061) 
will fill this gap.

In the meantime, as [already suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17061#issuecomment-451418859) 
into the aformentioned issue, this is a nice suggestion:

> Asking this 3rd party to change their library so that those union types are 
>   expressed as enums would solve this as enums generate a double mapped dictionary at runtime.

```
// type SomeType = "a" | "b" | "c";
enum SomeType {
  a,
  b,
  c,
}

let my_string = "a";
let isOk = SomeType.hasOwnProperty(my_string);

my_string = "z";
let isNotOk = SomeType.hasOwnProperty(my_string);
```