# What's the meaning of typeof Array[number] in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typeof

```js
const names = ['jacob', 'master jung', 'kyuhyun'] as const;
type Names = typeof names[number];
```

[image]

I got the results I wanted, but I don't understand `typeof names[number]`.

What does `typeof Array[number]` in Typescript mean?

Comment: Also the editor also does not provide hints about the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof` gets the type of `names` variable (which is `readonly ['jacob', 'master jung', 'kyuhyun']`) then array/tuple member type is resolved. This is called indexed access types or [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

> Syntactically, they look exactly like an element access, but are written as types

In this case we "query" the type of tuple member (tuple/array at index) which is `'jacob' | 'master jung' | 'kyuhyun'`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5AK3lACMcAaGHReaZAJxjwFcwBzMigawE9GALHsDgC6MajFCQoAbgBQULgAdkMAHJJUGGPKUgAZnHUQsYRoiJ0hUmAHprMAEQFi9mAB8HVGvSasX7+9x8AvZAA)

Answer (score 26):

There is a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528780/typescript-check-typeof-against-custom-type/51529486#comment105389691_51529486) made by the user @jcalz that explains how it works. It refers to the following code, which is similar to the OP code:

```
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grape"] as const;
export type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number]; 'apple'|'banana'|'grape';
```

> `typeof fruit` is `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">`, so `Fruit` is
> equivalent to `(Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">)[number]`. The
> syntax `T[K]` means: the type of the properties of `T` whose keys are
> of type `K`. So `(Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">)[number]` means
> "the types of the properties of `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">`
> whose keys are of type `number`", or: "the array elements of
> `Array<"apple" | "banana" | "grape">`, or: `"apple" | "banana" | "grape"`.

And another similar [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values#comment99063812_45257357) by that user that adds a bit more technical terms:

> The type `T[K]` is a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) which gets the type of the property
> of `T` whose key is `K`. In `(typeof list)[number]`, you're getting
> the types of the properties of `(typeof list)` whose keys are
> `number`. Arrays like `typeof list` have [numeric index
> signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types),
> so their `number` key yields the union of all numerically-indexed
> properties.

Comment: I find the first quote much more understandable and the second quote is confusing, because the first quote says "whose keys are **of type** K", while the second quote says "whose key is K". Maybe to people, who are already familiar with TS, both explanations look identical, but to me they are day and night. The 1st really makes me to understand what `T[K]` means, while the second only makes it worse. :)

Answer (score 1):

@OfirD's answer is great and I recommend reading it first, but it didn't really click for me until I saw the same concept applied to an array **and** an object, side-by-side.

[I've taken the liberty of breaking down your original example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5AK3lACMcAaGHReaZAJxjwFcwBzMigawE9GALHsDgC6MajFCQoAbgBQAejkwlMAHoB+GVC4AHZDAAqO5AHkAZgDkkqDDC26QpuFYiyFy9ZqMxLKNJkO6Zj6oWGCMiER0Qq6KSh7yiiC0AJYsyQgANjAZ1LAZ6cgAXJ66MMYpaZnBEAF6mHbIDk6+oeGRtNEJ7hpdRIywAO688LDJjgAGCL7jMAPUgrDjYhLQ4xorsFOoAOrJULwg-QCCEADC4NA2uATE7JS5dAzMbOQ43HwCwlIwbvq8yWh4LRaPAuDAATBEP14EQMsgAHQGXh6ABu8AyjGswHgYHEw1YehyUDo8K63RKelqQWcu32hygJ3OkhsDSaWwgtIOxzOF2kZNUGga3hpey5DJ5zP8Rmpvk59MZvNaESiMXJMiAA):

[image]

I think line 5 is the most important part to understand: it takes an array type (`readonly ["jacob", "master jung", "kyuhyun"]`) and returns the types that would result from indexing by a number. Since the compiler knows exactly what elements are in the array, the answer is `"jacob" | "master jung" | "kyuhyun"`.

[Now let's use another example, an object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JClAyrsvQABWYpJms-pZlycGJjICaCogz7SN8PJ4jsoqSGsn4gMwNBproVZwVuO7NlA9JQIwoCtMwwTyBmrhOi6ZSuhcPw9EY9E1tujbMeEZiLJYNiPA40DiYxUlyM4MATkMrh-qiMC3DgQFYS+0jxph8HImoRwBKuMAmLmPLSCm3QGGJm51mpxbntIEAaMAyZHOKAScjAKZgkkqTpJkGb8tA8CMKR9gptAzAwSmwmGn8EAqR5u4tgG7Qgsp7mSXlLzhbCgwIgMxTlJU1QGlcjTZSVTFyLWARQAAIvAd5gDKRzgEChVKVAOWlcxXS6K5fRadVGBAA). We want a type of all keys, and a type of all values:

[image]

I think line 12 is the most important part to understand: it gets the type of a `test` (which you can see defined on line 2), and then says, "what would be the type if we indexed it by its own keys?" As you can see, that would be a union of `test`'s values.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with a type of `Names` has to be an item in the array.

Now, you can do:

```
const value: Names = "jacob"
```