# Typescript: Validate custom type of string array

Tags: typescript

I've recently tried to check if a variable is of a custom type (which consists in my case of several different strings).
I found this other post [Typescript: Check "typeof" against custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528780/typescript-check-typeof-against-custom-type)
which discusses exactly how to do a validator for this kind of type.

```
const fruit = ["apple", "banana", "grape"];
export type Fruit = (typeof fruit)[number];
const isFruit = (x: any): x is Fruit => fruit.includes(x);
```

I am however struggling to apprehend this instruction:

```
(typeof fruit)[number]
```

How does it work? I understand that `typeof` is [Typescript's query type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/doc/spec.md#3.8.10) but I really don't get what the `[number]` means.
It is supposed to "*define your Fruit type in terms of an existing array of literal values*"

Comment: is it `[number]` or is there an actual numeric, e.g., `[3]`?

Comment: it is [number] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the type for `typeof fruit` you get: `type AllFruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'grape'];`.

> You might need to make the array `readonly` to get this result
>   (i.e. `const fruit = <const>['apple', 'banana', 'grape'];`).

You can then index this type:

```js
type Apple = AllFruit[0]; // 'apple'
type Grape = AllFruit[2]; // 'grape'

type AppleGrape = AllFruit[0 | 2]; // 'apple' | 'grape'
```

So the `[number]` is pretty much just indexing every value in the array:

```js
type Fruit = typeof fruit[0 | 1 | 2]; // 'apple' | 'banana' | 'grape'
type Fruit = typeof fruit[number]; // 'apple' | 'banana' | 'grape'
```

Hope that helps.