# Use const values as union type options Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this example:

```
const FIRST = "FIRST"
const SECOND = "SECOND"

type TOptions = FIRST | SECOND

const someFunction = (options: TOptions): void => {
    // do something, no return
}
```

I like to use const values in type declaration

```
type TOptions = FIRST | SECOND // not working
```

to restrict the range of selection. These const are used across the entire project, so it will be unwise to not to use them and type it like this:

```
type TOptions = "FIRST" | "SECOND" // working, as expected
```

I don't want to repeat myself and like to use `const` values as type union options.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use `typeof` to make it work:

```
const FIRST = 'FIRST'
const SECOND = 'SECOND'

type TOptions = typeof FIRST | typeof SECOND;

const someFunction = (options: TOptions): void => {
// do something, no return
}

someFunction(FIRST); // works
someFunction('test'); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSQEoGUAqMC8MDkjVo4BQoksKAogMIDyAcgCJa6W2PFFQCeADgKYw0NHlACW4CM278QAM3jJ0MAD4xpfOTFb0GAbiIkJsCCAC2fOAFcwwMeGYAKECPGQAXIOF3IASg8A3EFEAEywAPhgAbyIAehiYYJAYE3MoAAtRMABzABoYMCSAJz4oS0KwIgBfAxSLa1tXB3x0H30iWqsbbwccKD5oHFaiIA)

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529486/11069163) helps me clarify your answer and usage of `typeof` operator in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare those constants as types:

```
// It's a good idea to export these types 
// since you want them to be used external files
export type FIRST = "FIRST"
export type SECOND = "SECOND"

export type TOptions = FIRST | SECOND

// and then a call to your function will be
someFunction("FIRST") // ok
someFunction("SECOND") // ok
someFunction("THIRD") // Argument of type '"THIRD"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TOptions'.(2345)
```

Another option is to use an enum type:

```
export enum Options {
  FIRST = 'FIRST',
  SECOND = 'SECOND'
}

const otherFunction = (options: Options) => {}

otherFunction(Options.FIRST)
otherFunction(Options.SECOND)
```