# Interface restrict key value to be exact value of a const Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I like to extend my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753985/use-const-values-as-union-type-options-typescript) and ask for a help with `interface` example:

```
const FIRST = "FIRST"
const SECOND = "SECOND"

interface TSomeInterface {
    element: Element
    order?: typeof FIRST | typeof SECOND // not working, value could be anything
}
```

How do I restrict the optional `order` key to one of the `const` above?

To be clear, I want:

```
{ element: someElement, order: FIRST } // pass
{ element: someElement, order: SECOND } // pass
{ element: someElement, order: "test" } // fail
{ element: someElement, order: "" } // fail
{ element: someElement, order: 0 } // fail
```

Comment: Putting your code into the typescript playground already notifies of the invalid value for order. Are you sure your code is not working as intended? Maybe it's a typescript version issue?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, looks like it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet is already [working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pjbhaa).

Check your typescript configuration and as @Yoshi said, your typescript version.