# How to test custom type in typescript for example for type ORDER = 'WALK' | 'RUN'?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to get ORDER for takeOrder('WALK') instead of string, typeof cannot work for that :

```
type ORDER = 'WALK' | 'RUN'

function takeOrder(order: ORDER) {
    console.log (order);
    console.log (typeof order);
}

takeOrder('WALK'); // doesn't give ORDER
takeOrder('SLEEP'); // string
```

Comment: `console.log` happens at *runtime*, when the `type` definition doesn't exist at all. Look at the .JS output at the right-hand side in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gSgEQKJygXigcgOoEEAyA0plAD5ZwCqAcpgFB0BmArgHYDGwAlgPatTAAhgGsIMAE4ATCOIAUPKTIBcsRCgCUUAN50oeqOz4BnHgBsIAOlM8A5lHmLx6gNy79h1ifNXb90JB5GKAVpJ1cAXwYhUQlQ2RwCYhcoAHoUqEkeCCNWTGAoGy4AN2h4ZDg6aLFHeIBlfCQkAAVMZLSoI2BxLlYbOiA, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so what, that I know or I wouldn't have asked the question, my question is HOW I could, typescript can provide a mechanism for that.

Comment: You can't. *TypeScript* can't. The type information is erased, because JavaScript doesn't have types. It's not clear what you mean when you say *"test custom type"* - if you want to know whether it's working, doesn't the fact that you can't compile code that doesn't pass either `'WALK'` or `'RUN'` to `takeOrder` tell you that?

Answer (score 0):

All typescript types are erased at runtime so basically there is no way to know the them at runtime. But if you want to narrow down the types in a conditional block, then you should use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). the closest thing you can do is like this:

```
type ORDER = 'WALK' | 'RUN'

function takeOrder(order: ORDER) {
    if (order === 'WALK' || order === 'RUN') console.log('ORDER')
}
```

I also recommend that you take a look at this [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528780/typescript-check-typeof-against-custom-type). it's quite close to what you asked.