# Refine to type alias in union

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

I'm trying to check if a value of a union type is one of the union'd types.

In the code below, the first three approaches (1-3) seem to not be the correct one.

The checking for a specific property approach (4) seems to work, although it's unclear which type it has refined into.

1. Into which type it has refined in (4) (`A` or `B`)?
2. Why either a number or string can't be assigned to `a1.a` in (5) and (6)?
3. Which would be the correct way to refine to one of the types in a union, where the type is not a primitive (i.e. is a type alias)?

```js
type A = {
  a: number
}

type B = {
  a: string
}

const a1: A | B = {a: 1}

if (typeof(a1) === 'A') {}    // (1) Cannot compare the result of `typeof` to string literal `A` because it is not a valid `typeof` return value
if (a1 instanceof A) {}       // (2) Cannot reference type `A` [1] from a value position
(a1: A)                       // (3) Cannot cast `a1` to `A` because string [1] is incompatible with `A` [2]

if (a1.a) {                   // (4) Works, but inconclusive?
  a1.a = 2                    // (5) Cannot assign `2` to `a1.a` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2]
  a1.a = '2'                  // (6) Cannot assign `'2'` to `a1.a` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2]
}
```

Comment: (4) doesn't work, both `0` and `""` are falsy, and both `1` and `"x"` are truthy.

Comment: I would have expected `typeof a1.a === "number"` to work (true = `A`, false = `B`), and it does  in TypeScript, but Flow [doesn't seem to like it](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKA7ArgLYBGEATigL4oqiRQBCCyamOAzsGQJa4DmVGgGMA9rk6YAjDjgAfRswCyGYAAsAdGQy4AJiMIAKAJRQAPFAAM6gKxQA-MmxRJlKDiROARJM+UA3DTcAGZQBnQQIiEYkuoYCPCIngQk5J4mqOjRscwATAGuEAA27NAZUtmIAOQ5lfkoQA)... :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry I didn't get about `0` and `""` being falsy and `1` and `"x"`, truthy. Could you write the statements which are falsy and truthy? Thanks

Comment: (4) is `if (a1.a)`, but that doesn't do anything to tell you whether `a1` is an `A` or a `B`, because it will be false for both `0` (a number) and `""` (a string), and it will be true for both `1` (a number) and `"1"` (a string). That is, both `0` and `""` are *falsy* values (values that coerce to `false` when used in conditions). The full set of falsy values is: `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false` (also `document.all` on browsers for...reasons). All other values are *truthy*.

Comment: Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528780/typescript-check-typeof-against-custom-type

Comment: @secan, About the runtime erase, I know, but was thinking about a design-time `typeof` behavior in Flowtype, of which there seems to be one, but about constructing new values instead of checking for types. About checking for known values of the type, that's not a solution because I'm looking for a design-time solution and that's runtime. About the type-guard solution, it uses a 'is' keyword exclusive to Typescript, so, not available in Flowtype.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, I see. So that's the runtime behavior of JavaScript, in use? I was thinking that was treated by Flowtype at design-time doing some kind of typechecking inside of its type system. Really, looking at some random Flowtype/Typescript code now, it's not immediately clear what's treated by the compiler, and what's left for JavaScript. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm gonna walk through this code just to clarify what's going on:

```js
type A = {
  a: number
}

type B = {
  a: string
}

const a1: A | B = {a: 1}
```

The constant `a1` has been declared to be of the type that is a union of two object types, `A` and `B`.

```js
if (typeof(a1) === 'A') {}    // (1) Cannot compare the result of `typeof` to string literal `A` because it is not a valid `typeof` return value
```

The problem here is that we're confusing value-level with type-level. This is sort of confusing because flow shares its [type-level `typeof` keyword](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/) with [javascript's value-level `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). These are two different things and don't interoperate. We can consider the type-level flow `typeof` syntax to be a compile-time operation and the value-level javascript `typeof` syntax to be a runtime operation. The important thing about this distinction is that while flow has *some* awareness of values at compile-time, javascript has *no* awareness of types at runtime.

So in this example we're getting a runtime value `typeof(a1)` and trying to figure out how to compare it with the compile-time type `A`, and use this comparison for type refinement. The problem with this is that type refinement must operate at both compile-time and runtime, but runtime will have no awareness of the type `A`. Here we're trying to figure out how to refer to `A` because flow does not give us a way to do this:

```js
if (typeof(a1) === 'A') // How can we refer to `A` at runtime? We can't.
```

The other problem here is that `typeof a1` is going to return `'object'` in all cases because this is literally just the regular javascript runtime `typeof` keyword, and `typeof` returns `'object'` for all object instances.

```js
if (a1 instanceof A) {}       // (2) Cannot reference type `A` [1] from a value position
```

This is basically the same problem, but it's more clear what's going on in this example. Flow is telling us exactly what the problem is, we're trying to reference a type (`A`) from a value position, rather than a type position. `instanceof` is runtime check, so it can't be used to compare against types.

```js
(a1: A)                       // (3) Cannot cast `a1` to `A` because string [1] is incompatible with `A` [2]
```

Here we're attempting a [type cast / assertion](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/), which doesn't work basically because `a1` has not yet been refined to `A`, and it so as far as flow knows it could still be `B`, and it would be unsafe to not deal with that case.

```js
if (a1.a) {                   // (4) Works, but inconclusive?
  a1.a = 2                    // (5) Cannot assign `2` to `a1.a` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2]
  a1.a = '2'                  // (6) Cannot assign `'2'` to `a1.a` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2]
}
```

This is actually a valid refinement operation, but it only refines the *property* `a1.a` as existing. For example we can do something like this:

```js
type A = {
  member: string,
};

type B = {

};

declare var c: A | B;

if (c.member) {
  console.log(c.member); // c.member is of type `mixed`
}
```

([try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUC2EMCMICcAuKAZ2HwEsA7AcwBoUBfAbhRVEigCEFk2W2AEwgBjADYBDfNABuUqCOJwAPt1YoKAMygAKEQDosuAgEo+6EQHsqJS2Ij6xlmnsPY8+E60ZA))

Here we have refined `c.member` to existing, but we don't know anything else about it so its type is `mixed`. This means we can't do that much with it. The important thing here, is that the type of `c` is still `A | B`, refining its property did not refine the containing type at all.

Now let's get to the real question:

> Which would be the correct way to refine to one of the types in a union, where the type is not a [union of] primitive [types] (i.e. is a [union of object types])?

If the goal is to actually refine at the top level which object type something is, there is currently only one way to do this in flow: Use a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions). A disjoint union relies on a special flag member of object types that *must be of a different [literal type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/) for each member of the union.* This means that if you use something like `string` it won't be recognized as a disjoint union:

```js
type A = {
  // We're calling this `type` but it could have any name as long
  // as it's the same among each member of the union.
  type: 'a', // This must be a literal type.
  aMember: string,
};

type B = {
  type: 'b', // This must be a different literal type.
  bMember: number,
};

declare var c: A | B;

if (c.type === 'a') {
  // Within this branch, type of `c` is `A`.
  (c.aMember: string);
  // $FlowFixMe
  (c.bMember: number);
} else {
  // Within this branch, type of `c` is `B`.
  (c.bMember: number);
  // $FlowFixMe
  (c.aMember: string);
}
```

([try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUD0GoHUIHIAnaAYwEMAbCgSwDsBzKYAC2oGcoADUSTqAIwCuwKNREkA9oIoATKMzIA3aGVogotMgFsVHChIZpM2MhzH4OLaG20qtBxhDIlmUHVv4RCUCQDMmzNCCtNQGAHRGPBAAXFD4ZPgANMZQACqsHFqCbCKeUGRQNMBelEzgEBHoZACyEB5esTmEdPSJKAC+ANwoKFFQAEIIyJHlsfj8SSnp7G7ZuSpQMtS+vl4QtCJFJRRlkJUCtfWEsbSCR21dPTIQJBRkxFCK91AksXAAPgPdKMtQABQkMJ9eAguIJACUw3QWFwYlYtACM34hFULmSfT8XBIfBmnBgnH2ALCNTqnmOUCaLXB3Wh2AAJAAxfQAdwZ1AAHrUjET+IcySczmTqR0oBAKGxoKhabCWHRERxkajmOjyj5-JxsaIOJx+gTuYDeaSGhpBV5hdLGSy2ZyIPriXzjZSGML2kA))