# How to check if generic type is defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some utils that looks like that :

```
export const localStorageToPaginationOptions = <T extends LocalStorage, U>({
  searchTerm,
  filters,
  sortBy,
  orderAsc,
  ...props
}: T & U): PaginationOptions | U => ({
    ...props,
    search: searchTerm,
    orderMode: orderAsc ? OrderMode.asc : OrderMode.desc,
    orderBy: sortBy,
    filters,
  });
```

I would like the function to return either the PaginationOptions type or the U type if it has been declared in the function call. Is there anyway of doing that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529486/2902996 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional return type where you check if `unkown` extends `U`. Note that you are gonna need a type assertion for the return value as TypeScript is generally not able to understand implementations of functions with generic return types.

```
export const localStorageToPaginationOptions = <T extends LocalStorage, U>({
  searchTerm,
  filters,
  sortBy,
  orderAsc,
  ...props
}: T & U): unknown extends U ? PaginationOptions : U => ({
    /* ... props ... */ 
  } as unknown extends U ? PaginationOptions : U);
```

This leads to the following behavior when called:

```
const a = localStorageToPaginationOptions({})
// const a: PaginationOptions

const b = localStorageToPaginationOptions<LocalStorage, { something: "for U" }>({})
// const b: {
//    something: "for U";
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Looks to be good, thanks !