# Next.js runs fine under yarn dev, but throws a type error when run next export

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, web-deployment

I have a type interface call PageInformation

```
export interface PageInformation extends SanityBody{
    _type: "pageInformation";
    address: string;
    backgroundInformation: string;
    email: string;
    role: string;
    heroImage: Image;
    title: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    profilePic: Image;
}
```

In my Hero section I imported the interface and passed it into Props

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import PageInformation from "../typings";
import {urlFor} from "../sanity";


type PageInformation = typeof PageInformation;

type Props = {
    pageInformation: PageInformation;
};
```

In the rendering I need a url helper function to get the url by access heroImage property, but it throws a type error, which is ok when run under yarn dev

```
<img 
        className="relative rounded-full h-36 w-36 mx-auto object-cover"
        src={urlFor(pageInformation?.heroImage).url()}
        />
```

Below is the error message I got, which made me clueless, because I indeed has defined heroImage property for PageInformation interface.

```
Type error: Property 'heroImage' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/yudonglu/Desktop/Study/Web/my-portfolio/typings")'.

  31 |      <img 
  32 |      className="relative rounded-full h-36 w-36 mx-auto object-cover"
> 33 |      src={urlFor(pageInformation?.heroImage).url()}
     |                                   ^
  34 |      />
  35 | 
  36 |      <div className='z-10'>
```

These are the interface i defined for pageInformation

```
 interface SanityBody{

    _createdAt: string;
    _id: string;
    _rev: string;
    _updatedAt: string;
}

interface Image{

    _type: "image";
    asset: {
        _ref: string;
        _type: "reference";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, it’s only legal to use typeof on identifiers (i.e.
> variable names) or their properties. This helps avoid the confusing
> trap of writing code you think is executing, but isn’t:

from this [Typescript: Check "typeof" against custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528780/typescript-check-typeof-against-custom-type)

> You can't use typeof at runtime to check for interface types, which
> only exist at compile time.

so in dev environment, there was no type checking in the img src, that is why you were fine. Looks like this is creating issue:

```
type PageInformation = typeof PageInformation;
```

Intead just use the imported `PageInformation` interface

```
import PageInformation from "../typings";
```