# Literal type, is it possible to extract the list of values at runtime

Tags: typescript, typing

Also worth to check this ohter similar question (first updated answer) [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

```
type Direction = 'north' | 'east' | 'south' | 'west';

let direction:Direction = 'south';                      // OK

let xtern = JSON.parse(`{"dir":"wrong"}`);    // (from external source, needs validation
```

What I want to do is to validate that xtern.dir fits in the type Direction without repeating the list of possible values but I think there's no way to extract the list of values in a literal type, right? If so, what could be a concise way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You could use an `enum` or an array

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind sacrificing a bit of compile time safety, an `enum` would work here:

```
enum Direction {
    North = "north",
    East = "east",
    South = "south",
    West = "west",
}

let direction1: Direction = Direction.South;      // This works
let direction2: Direction = Direction["south"];   // This also works!
let direction3: Direction = Direction["rubbish"]; // But this returns undefined  
                                                  // rather than a compiler error...

let xtern = JSON.parse(`{"dir":"wrong"}`); 
let isValidDir = Direction.hasOwnProperty(xtern.dir); // Can examine it at runtime
```

But if you want to keep using a string literal union as you are now, your only option is currently to write the validation yourself, and keep it in sync with the type definition. This approach is demonstrated in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).