# Create String Literal Types dynamically

Tags: typescript

I have defined the following type:

```js
type UserConfigCategories = 'tables-config' | 'link-config' | 'general-config';
```

however this type can grow and I do not want to have to update it.
Is it possible to create this type dynamically from an array, for example?

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by "dynamically"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: Create it with code by iterating an array and not defining it literally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Answer (score 4):

If the array defining the categories is a literal somewhere in your source you can infer the type from the values with `as const` added in 3.4.

```js
const CONFIG_CATEGORIES = ['tables-config', 'link-config', 'general-config'] as const;
type UserConfigCategories = (typeof CONFIG_CATEGORIES)[number]

const u: UserConfigCategories = 'tables-config';
const v: UserConfigCategories = 'bad-name'; // Type '"bad-name"' is not assignable to type 
                                            // '"tables-config" | "link-config" | "general-config"'.
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the problem is that, nowhere in the code the categories is a literal.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case it is not possible. Consider the fact that types are checked at compile time which means typescript needs the information before any code runs. If the values are truly dynamic as you say, `string` is the only thing that can type it without nominal typing in the language.

Comment: I get it. It makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your clear response.

Comment: It should be possible. This is what generics are for.