# Dynamically create string literal type from a string

Tags: typescript

Is there way to dynamically create a string literal type from a string, other than making an array from the string and then extracting its type using typeof, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692481/6787953)?

```
const url = 'text'
const URL = [url]
type P = (typeof URL)[number];
```

EDIT
What I am trying to achieve is build, a method which based on the given string(endpoint URL) will be able extract required by that endpoint params which I need to provide.

```
export type ExtractRouteParams<T> = string extends T
? Record<string, string>
: T extends `${infer _Start}:${infer Param}/${infer Rest}`
? { [k in Param | keyof ExtractRouteParams<Rest>]: string }
: T extends `${infer _Start}:${infer Param}`
? { [k in Param]: string }
: {};
```

ExtractRouteParams is a type which based on the given string return my type which defined what kind of params are needed. Its works completely fine when I use it like that.

```
type Test = ExtractRouteParams<'actions/:actionId/test/:testId'>
```

But I would like it to work more dynamicaly. I have create an factory URL method within which I want to create type based on the URL provided as parameter. That method return generic class (Based on that dynamic type) which contain method to create url.

```
export function urlFactory(url: string) {
  type P = typeof url;
  return new InterpolateUrl<P>();
}

class InterpolateUrl<T extends string> {
  url(params: ExtractRouteParams<T>): void {

  }
}

const endpoints = {
    endpoint: urlFactory(
       'actions/:actionId/test/:testId'
    )
};
```

Unfortunately InterpolateUrl class method **url** does not properly points required **params**. In compared, type Test does.

Here [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIZQIYGMYBKEArjMAArY4C2AzgDwAqAfHALxy1YCWAdgOZxQZXgBNacRgCg4suAH44BYLmij6XKH34AaTjwHMZcgFyShmYGIkADACQBvPgDNgUOAH0AyjCowAviaOLm5wlDT%20APTBvK7uylz%20Nsayig5wANoA1nB8YVTY1HAAPnBZwIgQzuiYOPhEpBQFdPQJMMwAumaa2nD%20KXBmjBYi4nD2TrGh3r6wgTFx%20RHJcgpw6dm5vEuFXfpaAn0DZg7%20ANxSUkgoksBc7DVYeIQkZOGFDADkz9wQvLSREw-P4ASVEkTIXEBkJgYM%20RikoEgsDgzmIvHwv22xCgABsAGLPaCIAAUONx3QM-AAlOtjNdUOQHgyqnByRdZFBgDAcdteMAAO5wEG8MhQSC47BkACqePo5GYJOpF36UlwktoEhFYolUuAstxTBGVjGPUMdNk5JJYGatDMGCe9VeTRoDBY1LMADcINxRHTjP1Vap-vATZA%20DAJBwHAMwz7RWZyYT8MSSQM5N9MX8AUCs7wwRC7jBoUW4QNqVJzpdg7QILjgAA6XEQfgkuMR2gN9uihtWmP%20akVoA)

Comment: What is "dynamically" supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: That's it's provided as param to the method and within that method I need to create type from that.

Comment: Not sure I follow. TypeScript is a *static* type checker, but you want it to react to dynamic parameters? Even the question you linked explains that this is not possible (see the comments).

Comment: Maybe I wrote it wrong. At the moment of starting the app the URL is defined as in the example, but I have a few of them and would like to extract type individually for all of the predefined values within that method. Here is an playground. I would like to extract properly all the parameters needed by my endpoint based on it's URL using custom type. Link to playground -> shorturl.at/evzCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

Given your updated question and example, it looks like all you want is for your `urlFactory()` function to itself be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  The compiler doesn't really look at a specific type like `string` and treat it generically because the output type would be better for you; you have to tell the compiler when you want generics:

```
export function urlFactory<P extends string>(url: P) {
  return new InterpolateUrl<P>();
}
```

Once you do that, things works as desired, I think:

```
console.log(endpoints.endpoint.url({
  actionId: "hey",
  testId: "you"
})); // okay

console.log(endpoints.endpoint.url({
  // error!
  // Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 
  // '{ actionId: string; testId: string; }': actionId, testId
}))
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIZQIYGMYBKEArjMAArY4C2AzgDwAqAfHALxy1YCWAdgOZxQZXgBNacRgCg4cAPxwCwXNFH0uUPvwA0nHgOYy4ALklDMwMRIAGAEgDefAGbAocAPoBlGFRgBfYwdnVzhKGj8AeiDeFzclLj9rIwV7OABtAGs4PlCqbGo4AB84DOBECCd0TBx8IlIKPLp6eJhmAF1TDS04PyNTRnMRcTg7RxiQrx9YAOjY3PCk2RT0rJyw-I69TQEevrh7PwBuKSkkFElgLnYqrDxCEjJ1poByO+4IXloI4zePgElRBEyFxvsCYADnoYpKBILA4E5iLx8O9eHBiFAADYAMTu0EQ9HIg0swy6BgAFOiMaZyABKfZGKDAGDo1G8YAAdzgf14ZCgkAx2DIAFVMQTmGSacdelJcALaBJubz+YLgCKMUwiVYtlpWPYjJSyWBGrRTBhbrUHg0aAwWDTTAA3CDcUT0oy9aUqT7wYmQPgwCQcPWyH1OnmmSk4-B4slGWSvZEfL4-BO8AFAy4wUEZiFGGlSI4nT20CAY4AAOgxEH4ZJDftoZdrPLLBqDcF+qdEpgARAALMpd7RGMEA7vlYhd-M0vMyxMl8uV6uN-0NsS+pstowRCJCKBQaAAQk328YyFQzwOz2yEmo3Hl3RgffhJcr7O6YD3KFg3Eu8L3BTOqBHnA55timI7agIhwINmnYQfwUF+M8pjtgCujDqIk55kAA)

---

**Original answer**

You can use the [TypeScript `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) directly on `url` without having to make an intervening array:

```
const url = 'text'
type P = typeof url;
// type P = "text"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgJwDYwLwwORQKYA8oYBQUAngA7YwAKaMpFIAZvMgNyED0Hd5lN6AIhz4BQA)

Comment: Can you look at my comment under my answer and here at my playground whether thing which I am trying to achieve is even possible -> shorturl.at/evzCS?

Comment: Hmm, that's a bunch of code and yet nothing obvious that jumps out as expected vs actual behavior; could you pare that down to a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue?  And ideally you'd put any such code in the text of your question and not just in external links.

Comment: Ok I have change a question and example as well

Comment: Thank you so much bro!!! It's what I have been looking for!!! :)