# Type definition of arrays

Tags: typescript, typedef, typescript-generics

A TypeScript beginner here.

I have the following type definition for a function:

```
type MappingCallback<A extends any[], B extends any[]> = (from: A[0], to: B[0]) => boolean

interface ArrayToCombine<A extends any[], B extends any[]> {
  array: B
  mapping: MappingCallback<A, B>
  propertyName: string
}

declare function augmentArray<A extends any[], B extends any[], C extends any[]>(
  base: A,
  arrays: [ArrayToCombine<A, B>, ArrayToCombine<A, C>]
) : A

export default augmentArray
```

Right now, if I add another element to the `arrays` parameter, I also have to add a new `ArrayToCombine<A, ?>` element to the type definition to work. Is there a way to make it dynamic, so each element in the arrays list will inherit the correct type, (the type is coming from the `array` property inside `ArrayToCombine` interface)

(Also, you can see I have to define extends any[] on each generic type, otherwise, VSCode underlines it as an error)

Please tell me if I should clarify something, or you need more info!

Comment: You *might* want `declare function augmentArray<A extends any[], BB extends any[][]>( base: A, arrays: { [K in keyof BB]: ArrayToCombine<A, Extract<BB[K], any[]>> }): A;`, but I can't tell if it matches the use case (ideally your [mcve] would include how you plan to call this thing).  And automatically inferring tuple types instead of array types is still a bit maddening; you might need to call a `tuple()` function as described in the TS3.0 update of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values/45257357#45257357).