# Add a new key in the dictionary?

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, object

I want to add multiple keys to the dictionary via loop. For example, when I create a key, that key already has its value.

I have the following scenario:

```
var keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
var dic = {}

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

    const key = keys[i]
    dic[key] = 'value' + i         
}
```

Note that I am adding several keys and already assigning the value of that key, but it does not work in TypeScript, so I have tested it works perfectly in [JavaScript](https://playcode.io/462959).

This line above has error. Note that I cannot add an element that is not contained in the array:

```
dic[key] = 'value' + i
```

> **Error details**
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.

How can I get my Array keys and assign it to the dictionary with the loop value?

Comment: *It does not work*: which code does not work? How does it not work? Post a minimal complete example which "does not work", tell what you're doing (compiling? running?) , tell what you expect to happen, and tell what happens instead.

Comment: What type do you want `dic` to be?  If you're okay with it being a dictionary of strings, then declare it as such (e.g., `var dic: { [k: string]: string } = {}`).  Keep in mind that "it does not work" doesn't really count as a description of the problem as described in the guidelines for creating a [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: Got it, I made it clear now the line that gives the error in TypeScript

Comment: jcalz, the code worked for me, I have to learn a lot yet

Comment: excuse my question but why not working with object and set attributes as keys  ? var Dic = {
 "one": "first", 
 "two": 2}

Comment: MoxGeek How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the type of `dic`

- Use `any`

```
var dic: any = {}
```

- Be more precise

```
var dic: Record<string, string> = {}
```

- Be even more precise

```
type Key = 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3' | 'key4'
var keys: Key[] = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']
var dic: Partial<<Record<Key, string>> = {}
```

- If the keys are static, then you can make it even better (credit to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values))

```
const keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'] as const; // TS3.4 syntax
type Key = typeof keys[number];
var dic: Partial<Record<Key, string>> = {
  "key1": "123"
}
```