# Derive return type keys from parameter keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following function call:

```js
const props = await es.getByIdsGrouped([
  { name: 'favorites', ids: favoriteIds },
  { name: 'views', ids: viewsIds },
]);
```

I need `props` to have the typed keys of `favorites|views` - `props.favorites` and `props.views` with values of X type:

```js
// typeof props
{
  favorites: string[],
  views: string[]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496276/typescript-derive-union-type-from-array-of-objects) but wasnt able to fit it to what Im trying to do.

Comment: So give a [mre] to illustrate the current status.