# Define a type as containing all, and only members of a union type

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like this:

```js
type A = "A" | "B" | "C"; 

type ArrayofA = //???

const arr1 : ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C"]; //ok
const arr2 : ArrayofA = ["A", "B"]; // not ok
const arr3 : ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]; //not ok
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the premise. That is that unions are unsorted, but arrays are sorted. `"A" | "B"` is equivalent to `"B" | "A"` but `["A", "B"]` is not equivalent with `["B", "A"]`.

Because of this the mapping works easier the other way:

```js
type ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C"];

type A = ArrayofA[number];

const arr1: ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C"]; //ok
const arr2: ArrayofA = ["A", "B"]; // not ok
const arr3: ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]; //not ok
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`const`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) assertion introduced in TypeScript 3.4.

Elaborating from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values) it should be like:

```
const atype = [["A", "B", "C"]] as const;

type A_B_C = typeof atype[0][number]; // "A" | "B" | "C"
type Arrayof_A_B_C = typeof atype[number]; // ["A" | "B" | "C"]

const v: Arrayof_A_B_C = ["A", "B", "C"]; // OK
const w: Arrayof_A_B_C = ["A", "B"]; // not OK

const b: A_B_C = "B"; // OK
const d: A_B_C = "D"; // not OK
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a `tuple`. The downside is it must be declared explicitly, so there aren't any handy shortcuts with type aliases or destructuring that I'm aware of.

```
type A = "A" | "B" | "C";

type ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C"];

const arr1: ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C"]; //ok
const arr2: ArrayofA = ["A", "B"]; // not ok
const arr3: ArrayofA = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]; //not ok
```

Comment: I want to derive the array type from the union type