# How can I avoid declaring the same strings both in type declaration and type guard?

Tags: typescript

In my code below I am declaring all allowed strings twice, once in the type declaration and once in the type guard. How can I rewrite my code to avoid this duplication?

```
// inspired by: https://github.com/mattdesl/parse-unit

export type ParsedValue = {
  value: number;
  unit: Unit;
};

type Unit =
  | "ch"
  | "ex"
  | "em"
  | "rem"
  | "in"
  | "cm"
  | "mm"
  | "pt"
  | "pc"
  | "px";

export function parseUnit(str: string | null): ParsedValue | null {
  if (!str) {
    return null;
  }

  var value = parseFloat(str);

  const match = str.match(/[\d.\-\+]*\s*(.*)/);
  const unit = match ? match[1] : "";
  if (!isUnit(unit)) {
    return null;
  }

  return { value, unit };
}

export function isUnit(str: string): str is Unit {
  return ["ch", "ex", "em", "rem", "in", "cm", "mm", "pt", "pc", "px"].includes(
    str
  );
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the current version after some suggestions. This verison doesn't work. On `return { value, unit }` I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ch" | "ex" | "em" | "rem" | "in" | "cm" | "mm" | "pt" | "pc" | "px"'.`

```
// inspired by: https://github.com/mattdesl/parse-unit

export type ParsedValue = {
  value: number;
  unit: Unit;
};

const units = [
  "ch",
  "ex",
  "em",
  "rem",
  "in",
  "cm",
  "mm",
  "pt",
  "pc",
  "px",
] as const;

type Unit = typeof units[number];

export function parseUnit(str: string): ParsedValue | null {
  if (!str) {
    return null;
  }

  var value = parseFloat(str);

  const match = str.match(/[\d.\-\+]*\s*(.*)/);
  const unit = match ? match[1] : "";
  if (!isUnit(str)) {
    return null;
  }

  return { value, unit };
}

export function isUnit(str: string): str is Unit {
  return ((units as unknown) as Array<string>).includes(str);
}
```

Comment: You can extract the answer from responses of SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: @AlekseyL: Not fully, I still get an error when I try to check if the str is included in the array at runtime, and then try to return a typed value, see edit

Comment: probably the easiest would be `isUnit(str: any)..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the array as a standalone variable, `as const` so its type doesn't get widened to `string[]`, then define the Unit type as `typeof units[number]`:

```
const units = ["ch", "ex", "em", "rem", "in", "cm", "mm", "pt", "pc", "px"] as const;
type Unit = typeof units[number];
export function isUnit(str: string): str is Unit {
  return (units as unknown as Array<string>).includes(str);
}
```

The `units` is a ReadOnlyArray which doesn't accept arbitrary strings to be passed to `.includes`, unfortunately, so it has to be turned into `Array<string>` by going through `unknown` first.

Comment: I get an error on 'return units.includes(str)': Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ch" | "ex" | "em" | "rem" | "in" | "cm" | "mm" | "pt" | "pc" | "px"'.

Comment: Oh, I see that too. That's unfortunate, it looks like you have to put it through `unknown` first so `.includes` can accept the string

Comment: Hmm, I am still not able to get this working. See the code I added in my edit

Comment: You're testing the wrong thing: `if (!isUnit(str)) {` but `str` is the input string before the regex has parsed it. Pretty sure you meant `if (!isUnit(unit)) {`