# How to extract a Union from an Array

Tags: typescript

I'm using [graphql-code-generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/) to generate TypeScript definitions from my GraphQL queries and currently trying to extract a specific union from an array. Is this possible in TypeScript? I've found [an example where someone extracted a type from a generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxQHYCuANkVAD5QF4AmEAZgJZ4TXlRoDcAUFxAB5gA9gCdgUUJFggAigQjCQOKFADeXZQH0NEiHjgBbCAC4oAclnyQpgDTqo1OMDgn4SVAAo7ytct9QG1CYAzsDCTADm3H7KeobBoRFR0YhwwvFheJFevlo6scZmACKOcACMptkAvtkUPtEB6YnZyjqNmUl+dIKCbVnRULngugYFpsVOAEwVftXKAJQY3NVcOlIWCuNlSgCifKFwAMbAKDAycgoA2gBEDk5XALrWqgPaQ-kmV5ulV5UYK0Nrc4gTYTHZ7YSHY6ndYga63OAPJ4qF55EYfEE-P5AA) and tried to make use if the `Extract` function, but this does not work and returns just `never`:

```js
export type Foo = Array<(
    {
      id: string;
      __typename: 'Data1'
    }
    | {
      id: string;
      __typename: 'Data2'
    }
  )>;

type MyQueryData1 = Extract<Foo, { __typename: "Data1"}>
type MyQueryData2 = Extract<Foo, { __typename: "Data2"}>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEJwLxwIJRQCGiAPABQBQcNcA3tbTQJYAmAXHAM4xTMB2AcwDcjJgH1xSFPyIBbYJwDkAESIwiARiVi4AX10AferpYduvASNNxJ04LIXK1GgEw6mBmgEoAfKMp7OABZRABFAFdgKEQXLRw4AFEQXiIAYxhSDAgAGnpbKWQHeUU4ACI4zTK9X0CikPComLjXBOTUjKzMPLoC+0dSivUiV2raoA)

Comment: Check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values/45257357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the result you want? [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEJwLxwIJRQCGiAPAFBxVwDel1VAlgCYBccAzjFIwHYDmAbnoMA+qKQpeRALbB2AcgAiRGEQCMCkXAC+2gD61tTNp258hxuOMnBpcxSrUAmLQz1UAfMPIB6XwjIqADujAA2YXAARqg0cCzsXDwCgtYSQfbycMqqGgq65LZwALKIAIoArsBQiE4aOHAAoiDcRADGMKQYEADavBUyMVAAugA0tGm2mewARHXqM7qe5H4BRaER0bHxpkkWqTYZslk5Lgp6RaWV1bW5zg3NrR1dmH0DQ2MTh1LHs3XOMx0yyAA)

If so you have to extract the type from the deirved union type from the element values of the array,

```
type MyQueryData1 = Extract<Foo[number], { __typename: "Data1"}>
type MyQueryData2 = Extract<Foo[number], { __typename: "Data2"}>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much :-)