# create custom type of large items list in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

A prequel to the question:
to create a custom type for a variable, lets say:

```
let x: 'abc'|'feg' | 'def'
```

so x can be only ONE of those.

Now, for the problem itself:
So in I have a large list of items, lets say:

```
let lstA = [    'Fonts Flash', 'Hardware Concurrency', 'Has Lied Browser', 'Has Lied Languages', 'Has Lied OS', 'Has Lied Resolution', 'Indexed DB', 'Language', 'Local Storage', 'Open Database', 'Pixel Ratio',   'Platform', 'Plugins', 'Screen Resolution', 'Session Storage'];
```

and i would like to create a new variable of a certain type, which would be **ONLY** of that item in **THAT** list,

how can i create it quickly, without writing '|' each time?

*using typescript 3.9

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/q/45251664/3001761?

Comment: yes. it seems about what I hoped for.
But it seems that it doesnt (the IDE: webstorm) make suggestions/auto complete.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - if you have a problem applying those answers, [edit] to give a [mre].

Comment: ok,  is it possible to do it for an object/enum?
for example:
export let lstB = {
    'Ad Block': 'Ad Block',
    'Add Behavior': 'Add Behavior',
    'Audio': 'Audio',
    'Available Screen Resolution': 'Available Screen Resolution',
    'Canvas': 'Canvas',
    'Color Depth': 'Color Depth'}