# How to generically constrain a parameter to be a member of a tuple?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript4.0

As of Typescript 4.0 with named tuples, I'm wondering if the following is possible:

```
declare const foo: <T extends string[], U extends memberOf T>(xs: T, x: U) => void

declare const ALL_OPTIONS: ['Alice', 'Bob']


foo(ALL_OPTIONS, 'Carl')  // Error
foo(ALL_OPTIONS, 'Alice') // No Error
```

Basically I'm trying to constrain `U` to an element of the tuple, something like `memberOf` might exist in the same way that you could use `keyOf` if `T` was an Object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: the potential duplicate does not answer the question directly, and the relevant information is buried deep in the answers. Importantly, I was unable to find it unless I specifically knew to search for `T[number]`; this question would help others find the answer to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `U extends T[number]`, like this:

```
declare const foo: <T extends string[], U extends T[number]>(xs: T, x: U) => void

declare const ALL_OPTIONS: ['Alice', 'Bob']


foo(ALL_OPTIONS, 'Carl')  // Error
foo(ALL_OPTIONS, 'Alice') // No Error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPADwAq8IAHhiCsGvJjAJYoDmA2gLoA08AquSo068EuxQBXALYAjEDE4A%20ABQU0hErwqE%20ASngBeRfABuSJsABQl0JFgJk6LAEEAMq4D6AeQAKJAJJeAHIAyoTsAOTOEExgIBG8EQBCSDIRnNaWuEjKbp6%20AcEhiQDCsBAR%20vAA9NXwAKIwMEgwWXi57t5%20gaGJ0bHx%20rXwQUgNTS1AA)

Comment: And also note that we don't even need TypeScript 4 for this, TS3.3 or maybe earlier still work.

Comment: @MingweiSamuel - Yeah. It might be 3.4 when `T[number]` was added, but I'm not sure of the precise release. :-)