# TypeScript - ValueOf Array - convert array generic to a union of its values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to convert a generic `T extends string[]` to a `ValueOf<T>` - which would be a union of all possible values in the generic array.

```
type ValueOf<T extends Array<any>> = unknown;

class Foo<T extends string> {
  public value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

/**
 * Transforms foo type to allow new values and sets foo value to the first element
 * of newAllowedValues if the current value does not match it.
 */
function transform<T extends string[]>(foo: Foo<string>, newAllowedValues: T): Foo<ValueOf<T>> {
  if (newAllowedValues.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('');
  }

  if (newAllowedValues.indexOf(foo.value) === -1) {
    foo.value = newAllowedValues[0];
  }

  return foo as unknown as Foo<ValueOf<T>>;
}

let foo1 = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>('a');

let foo2 = transform(foo1, ['b', 'c']); // now foo2 should be a Foo<'b' | 'c'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20IIROJ08oOVysHhOFJyts-h0faGRjAydh9Qh9TAAD4wfU2fVE%20tG7xl1OqABMeT0rCRrRdwh9NNxbf1NP1Mn1%20ONMAqFSGgw6g8oqWEKCQUxssAQNY5M%20brYX7GkQA)

Currently I could only find a solution for the case where array is a constant: [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

I know that I could achieve this by using an object rather than an array as `newAllowedValues` and relaying on `keyof` operator - but it's not pretty and I want to use this for a function that will be frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I linked earlier works for this case as well, I overlooked how it could be applied to a generic.

The searched ValueOf type is:

```
type ValueOf<T extends readonly string[]> = T[number];
```

and the array in the argument has to be passed as a const:

```
let foo2 = transform(foo1, ['b', 'c'] as const);
```

Full code:

```
type ValueOf<T extends readonly string[]> = T[number];

class Foo<T extends string> {
  public value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

/**
 * Transforms foo type to allow new values and sets foo value to the first element
 * of newAllowedValues if the current value does not match it.
 */
function transform<T extends readonly string[]>(foo: Foo<string>, newAllowedValues: T): Foo<ValueOf<T>> {
  if (newAllowedValues.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('');
  }

  if (newAllowedValues.indexOf(foo.value) === -1) {
    foo.value = newAllowedValues[0];
  }

  return foo as unknown as Foo<ValueOf<T>>;
}

let foo1 = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>('a');

let foo2 = transform(foo1, ['b', 'c'] as const); // now foo2 should be a Foo<'b' | 'c'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVKEAewEAdgCYDOUAThHKQPbEIhTnBUCWxA5gNoC6APigBeKNl7EkAWwBGEKvwDcAKBUBjBHHKUAYvXo48hEhVbsu3YQG8VUKGCSyEHdVABuiFAC5xqu1DqjGxUSOrA9FQAFJ7IEL7YAJRQtvb2wAAWHOQAdLEooh5eEKr2AL4qFSoA9ABUtXa14lRwxOTokdKUHfRQoJB9vYgI9ADuUMQQ4-kQlK2krBDA3QZFcYN9GdDoHFRseAgQ0iTAjVD06BNTAIIII6MQpPBxlByXmdDqSFQ0xMBrBQYswm9H%200jgwHUGSgHGAOUa1RU6CQxHCHEYfRabQ6VGkRgIRDIlBodEYzHMnB4AkEUR6vn0hhClkEABorqNbvdHs8UOQEol6QZMDy0FhsIIbAE3lAopMOXcxtzirlDjxMqIRGIAAzJVJpTJUMbsqAAUR%20kSiAHJLYlSlAqvZpbKbgqHk9lTkuKQCBhaQY8sVkpqxABaACMuoC9h6AfWYjlnMV7pevC1ygCDuoS2%20xCgPSg2igKIA1sQxrnCwzhcUMDgJaoqod-j0w4U5VAq5a4JaoAAfKCW2SWmldm3%20Jt5gwAJkK7Fa7U6fvoYbZvEHlrZlvUlv4BcoQTawFtUGq1RB4x6M-IGXoSAQC3kBY7QvXfYH28EaiAA)