# Check whether string exists in type

Tags: typescript

How do I check whether a string exists in a type?

**For example**

```
type Fruit = 'Apple' | 'Banana' | 'Orange';

const myFruit = 'Banana';

if( myFruit /* is in */ Fruit )
    console.log( 'myFruit is a fruit!' );
```

Comment: The type system does not exist at runtime. You cannot use runtime logic (an `if`) to interact with it. You need a concrete representation of this, so you can [have an array and get the type from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values) to be able to check it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `type` and `value`

Fruit is type

```
type Fruit = 'Apple' | 'Banana' | 'Orange';
```

myFruit is value

```
const myFruit = 'Banana';
```

There is no Fruit when typescript compiles to javascript

[image: playground]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a value you're looking for exists in a union type, you can't directly do that as others have mentioned since types don't exist in runtime in TypeScript. But you can use a tuple to "represent" that type in runtime and derive the union type you're looking for out of it like this.

```
// making sure `allFruits` is interpreted as a tuple of
// string literals insted of an array of strings
const allFruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"] as const;

type Fruit = typeof allFruits[number]; // 'Apple' | 'Banana' | 'Orange'

const myFruit = 'Banana';

if(allFruits.includes(myFruit))
    console.log('myFruit is a fruit!');
```

If the goal is to be able to narrow the `string` into a type `Fruit` through the if statement, you can use a [Type Guard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard) to infer that.

```
function isFruit(input: string): input is Fruit {
  return allFruits.includes(input as Fruit);
}

let maybeFruit = "Banana";
// type of `maybeFruit` here is `string` 
if (isFruit(maybeFruit)) {
  // type of `maybeFruit` here is `Fruit`
}
```