# type Alphabet = "a" | "b" into array ["a", "b"]

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I have a union type made of string literals in a third party types definition:

```
type Alphabet = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Now I would like to know if a string is of the given type:

```
const letterCandidate = "b"
// doesn't work: Alphabet.includes(letterCandidate)
```

One way to achieve that would be to make a string array out of the type:

```
// somehow get to: const arr: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"]
// then could: arr.includes(letterCandidate)
```

Is there any way to create some kind of iterable out of the Alphabet type?
Or some other solution to the problem?

Comment: Types are erased at runtime: so this feels like an XY problem. You should be defining the array, and then inferring the union type from the array values instead.

Comment: you can only convert it [the other way around](https://tsplay.dev/mb0XBw)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Comment: I see, the problem is I don't have write access to the third party library that defines the type. So I need to communicate to them to export an array from which to create the type, not just the type.