# Condition type if array includes all keys of interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface IYears {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
}

function transformYears(years: Array<keyof IYears>): [if all items of "years" includes in keyof IYears] ? IYears : Partial<IYears> {
  return years.reduce((acc, year) => ({
    ...acc,
    [year]: 'foo'
  }), {})
}

const yearsFirst = transformYears(['one', 'two']) // type of yearsFirst is Partial<IYears>

const yearsSecond = transformYears(['one', 'two', 'three']) // type of yearsFirst is IYears
```

How modified `transformYears` to match type of `yearsFirst` and `yearsSecond`? And possible check condition "if all items of "years" includes in keyof IYears" in ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the function generic to get this to work.

```
function transformYears<
  Y extends (keyof IYears)[]
>(years: [...Y]): Exclude<keyof IYears, Y[number]> extends never 
  ? IYears 
  : Partial<IYears> 
{
  return years.reduce((acc, year) => ({
    ...acc,
    [year]: 'foo'
  }), {}) as any
}
```

If we store the passed array in the generic type `Y`, we can use `Exclude` to compute the difference between `keyof IYears` and `Y[number]`. If `Y[number]` contains all keys of `IYears`, this evaluates to `never` which we can check for in the condition.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIE0JygZ2QbwChlkB7ECALmRzClAHMBuY5MAd1OtvpGdbAALKBCo06jFgF9ChGAFcQCMMHJsocEDhikoAW0zYcAHlbpkEAB6QQAEzwAKANYQAnqRhpDuAJQBtAF1CAD4HVyxcaj8AOlj0AJ9qAFFLBAAbeVsIYxd3TwwInAAaZHQ-EHk9ACNoAOCLawg7PAoAN2hkVgB+L0LOkmoABWwVODTjAqN6wiISETB5KBBkcKNokVt5JAcHRAQS1agfZABeeodZkmRY6L2i1hI-Q4DqAHIdUlfWKR8S-B-kHA8JpXIQZIQEORaCtCgAxYC4MCndSabS6AyFBx+V7kCCvEqvDifBLIAD0pLYrgADigPDCjPDEchgHhhlBRuNJrhgrJIVokYccABlCB82zIuionT6bw4LE4ij45CEzhKwnCUSvEnkyk0sieQWM6Es3pGIA)

---

After thinking about it, we can make it even a bit shorter:

```
function transformYears<
  Y extends (keyof IYears)[]
>(years: [...Y]): keyof IYears extends Y[number] ? IYears : Partial<IYears> {
  return years.reduce((acc, year) => ({
    ...acc,
    [year]: 'foo'
  }), {}) as any
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIE0JygZ2QbwChlkB7ECALmRzClAHMBuY5MAd1OtvpGdbAALKBCo06jFgF9ChGAFcQCMMHJsocEDhikoAW0zYcAHlbpkEAB6QQAEzwAKANYQAnqRhpDuAJQBtAF1CAD4HVyxcaj8AOlj0AJ9qF3dPDAi8Kxt7ZHQ-EHk9ACNoAOQAfi905GoABWwVOAAbYzSjYIJWETB5KBBkcKNokVt5JAcHRAQAGn6In2QAXnaHIhISWOjJqdYSPwGoAOoAch1SI9YpHxn8S+Q4PE1XQhlCBHJaWaMAMWBcMEX1JptLoDOkHH4juQIEcZkcOGcEsgAPRItiuAAOKA8n1wPz+yGAeDqUAazVauGCsjeWn++xwAGUINTbAC6ECdPpvDhwZCKDDkHDOPy4cJREdESi0ZiyJ46XiPoTKkYgA)

Comment: Thank for cool ideas! Based on your answer make [improvements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIE0JygZ2QbwChkTkB7ECALmRzClAHMBuY0sAdzJroZBbYkwACygRqtek1YBfQoRgBXEAjDAKyenBA4YZKAFtM2HAB5ByACrIIAD0ggAJngxZcAGgvob9iE7wAglBQcACepgDWEKFkMFYAfJ6kyACyPg7OyFExcdZ2GXjoANogigYARtAAusgA-FbINAAK2GpwADamlvGE8QAUoW44NEUAdOPoVQCUNGlEyWJgilAgyIMmo2KOikh9Fsl9iAjua25TyAC88ch988n3JOOjR0kP90XrUFU0AOR6ZD99qQZFNXg98DJkHA8CkLFNZPIEBQ6KcTAAxYC4MCXTQhHR6QzGXB9Io-CgQH4nH6cAHTZjIAD0DM0oQADihYqjcBischgHgWlA2p1XCYeoQkTpsZ8cABlCCSxw4rT4-RGIYksmUSnIalcHXU0TiH50xnMsBsjlxGU8lH8tBEnBAA)

Comment: Мove types to the header is good idea? Also do not understand how work construction ```keyof IYears extends Y[number]```, especially what mean ```Y[number]``` for ts, like instead of ```number``` put index 0, 1, 2,...length of ```years``` and result compared with keyof IYears, where to look to find out more?

Comment: `Y` is a generic type which holds the array you pass as the argument. We can now call `Y[number]` to get a union of all the elements inside of `Y` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)). When we use `keyof IYears extends Y[number]` we essentially check if every key in `IYears` is also in the union of the elements inside the array. If there are more strings in `keyof IYears` than in `Y[number]` the first one would not extend the second one anymore.

Comment: Thanks for help! I started to understand the syntax better