# Header is undefined, typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, payment

It is a payment method. The headers type is undefined. I am new to typescript and cannot spot the exact error.

Here is the error, it points to the headers in the if condition.

*Argument of type 'AxiosResponseHeaders | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dictionary'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary'.  TS2345*

```
(data, headers) => {    
    if (!this.validateResponse(headers, data)) {
        throw new Error('Signature verification failed')
    }
    return JSON.parse(data)             
}
```

And here is the whole file codes.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'






const CHECKOUT_ENDPOINT = 'https://services.paytrail.com'

type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T }

export interface CheckoutItem {
    /** Price per unit, VAT included, in each country's minor unit, e.g. for Euros use cents */
    unitPrice: number
    /** Quantity, how many items ordered */
    units: number
    /** VAT percentage */
    vatPercentage: number
    /** Merchant product code. May appear on invoices of certain payment methods. */
    productCode: string
    /** When is this item going to be delivered */
    deliveryDate: string
    /** Item description. May appear on invoices of certain payment methods. */
    description?: string
    /** Merchant specific item category */
    category?: string
    /** Unique identifier for this item. Required for Shop-in-Shop payments. */
    stamp?: string
    /** Reference for this item. Required for Shop-in-Shop payments. */
    reference?: string
    /** Merchant ID for the item. Required for Shop-in-Shop payments, do not use for normal payments. */
    merchant?: string
    /** Shop-in-Shop commission. Do not use for normal payments. */
    commission?: CheckoutComission
}

export interface CheckoutComission {
    /** Merchant who gets the commission */
    merchant: string
    /** Amount of commission in currency's minor units, eg. for Euros use cents. VAT not applicable. */
    amount: number
}

export interface CheckoutCustomer {
    /** Email */
    email: string
    /** First name */
    firstName?: string
    /** Last name */
    lastName?: string
    /** Phone number */
    phoneNumber?: string
    /** VAT ID, if any */
    vatId?: string
}

export interface CheckoutAddress {
    /** Street address */
    streetAddress: string
    /** Postal code */
    postalCode: string
    /** City */
    city: string
    /** County/State */
    county: string
    /** Alpha-2 country code */
    country: string
}

export interface CheckoutCallback {
    /** Called on successful payment */
    success: string
    /** Called on cancelled payment */
    cancel: string
}

export interface CheckoutPaymentOptions {
    /** Merchant unique identifier for the order */
    stamp: string
    /** Order reference */
    reference: string
    /**
     * Total amount of the payment in currency's minor units, eg. for Euros use cents.
     * Must match the total sum of items.
     */
    amount: number
    /** Currency, only EUR supported at the moment */
    currency: 'EUR'
    /** Payment's language, currently supported are FI, SV, and EN */
    language: 'FI' | 'SV' | 'EN'
    /** Array of items */
    items: CheckoutItem[]
    /** Cusomer information */
    customer: CheckoutCustomer
    /** Delivery address */
    deliveryAddress?: CheckoutAddress
    /** Invoicing address */
    invoicingAddress?: CheckoutAddress
    /** Where to redirect browser after a payment is paid or cancelled */
    redirectUrls: CheckoutCallback
    /** Which url to ping after this payment is paid or cancelled */
    callbackUrls?: CheckoutCallback
}

export interface CheckoutPayment {
    transactionId: string
    href: string
    /** Available payment methods. */
    providers: CheckoutProvider[]
}

export interface CheckoutProvider {
    url: string
    icon: string
    svg: string
    name: string
    group: string
    id: string
    parameters: CheckoutProviderParameter[]
}

export interface CheckoutProviderParameter {
    name: string
    value: string
}

// Helper type https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257357
const Tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args

// List of hashing algoritms supported by checkout.
const SupportedAlgorithms = Tuple('sha256', 'sha512')

export type CheckoutAlgorithm = typeof SupportedAlgorithms[number]

export function isSupportedAlgorithm(algorithm: string): algorithm is CheckoutAlgorithm {
    return SupportedAlgorithms.includes(algorithm as CheckoutAlgorithm)
}

export default class CheckoutApi {
    private readonly merchantId: string
    private readonly secret: string
    algorithm: CheckoutAlgorithm

    constructor(merchantId: string, secret: string, algorithm: CheckoutAlgorithm = 'sha512') {
        this.merchantId = merchantId
        this.secret = secret

        if (!isSupportedAlgorithm(algorithm)) {
            throw new Error(`${algorithm} is not supported signature algorithm`)
        }

        this.algorithm = algorithm
    }



    static calcMac(secret: string, algorithm: CheckoutAlgorithm, params: Dictionary<string>, body?: string): string {
        const hmacPayload = Object.keys(params)
            .filter(item => item.startsWith('checkout-'))
            .sort()
            .map(key => `${key}:${params[key]}`)
            .concat(body || '')
            .join('\n')

        return crypto
            .createHmac(algorithm, secret)
            .update(hmacPayload)
            .digest('hex')
    }


    validateResponse({ signature, ...params }: Dictionary<string>, body?: string): boolean {
        // Pull signature algorithm from params.
        const algorithm = params['checkout-algorithm']

        // Check that response is hashed with secure algorithm.
        if (!isSupportedAlgorithm(algorithm)) {
            throw new Error(`${algorithm} is not supported signature algorithm`)
        }

        // Check signature.
        return signature === CheckoutApi.calcMac(this.secret, algorithm, params, body)
    }

    public makeHeaders(method: string): Dictionary<string> {
        return {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
            'checkout-account': this.merchantId,
            'checkout-algorithm': this.algorithm,
            'checkout-method': method,
            'checkout-nonce': uuid(),
            'checkout-timestamp': new Date().toISOString(),
            
        }
    }

    createPayment(data: CheckoutPaymentOptions): Promise<CheckoutPayment> {
        return this.sendRequest('POST', `/payments`, this.makeHeaders('POST'), JSON.stringify(data))
    }

    
    sendRequest<T extends {}>(method: string, url: string, headers: Dictionary<string>, body?: string): Promise<T> {
        // Add signature header.
        headers.signature = CheckoutApi.calcMac(this.secret, this.algorithm, headers, body)
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

        return axios
            .post(url, body, {
                baseURL: CHECKOUT_ENDPOINT,
                
                responseType: 'json',
                transformResponse: [
                    (data, headers) => {
                        
                        if (!this.validateResponse(headers, data)) {
                            throw new Error('Signature verification failed')
                        }
                        

                        return JSON.parse(data)
                        
                    }
                ],
                headers
                
            })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data
            })
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the line which throws error.

Comment: This line:  if (!this.validateResponse(headers, data)) {

This is the github repository: https://github.com/hyrsky/checkout-psp-api/blob/master/src/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try to add | undefined in your signatures like so:

```js
sendRequest<T extends {}>(method: string, url: string, headers!: Dictionary<string>, body?: string): Promise<T> | undefined
```

Comment: It did not help. I get more error on other lines.