# Declare union type from a values of array

Tags: typescript

```
export const files = ['a', 'b', 'c']

export type File = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

How do I declare this File type without repeating the values like `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Comment: An uncanny duplicate: [Derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `typeof` with `number` as index syntax. Note that `as const` is needed in your array definition:

```
export const files = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
export type File = typeof files[number];
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYEsA2xVwC8cA2gOQCGZANHGQEY10JkC6cFBSaMA3AFD9QkWHBgBPMMDgAxXNOISpEDHGx5UJZAFcAtvWBRWvIA)