# Create array based on type

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type, let's say:

```
export type Fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "grape";
```

Is there a chance to construct an array containing those 3 fruits based on the given type?

As the type could be changed in the future, I try to have one source of truth and not duplicate the values of the type inside a new array.

Comment: Are you certain you want to create an array from a type? Because that's impossible. You can, however, very easily create a type out of an array with items. [Derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45251664)

Comment: ^^ https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EtYF4YG0BEBDABwIBsBTHAGhhwCM8x69LqBzBQ8gXRjwhlEhQA3ACgRUAJ4FSMAGLI0MTJOkg48BVCxgkAWxqkEnUTBgB6MzAB6AfhFA

Comment: @VLAZ I've needed it in the past for doing runtime type-checking based on static types written by a code-generation tool (Apollo GraphQL)